# RNAseq SNP discovery: deciding upon filters and dealing with allele expression bias

Tags: rna-seq, snp, transcriptome, filtering, genotyping

I am working with non-model plant RNA samples which we have been deep sequenced and analysed using STAR aligner under default parameters.

**Aim** We would like to conduct SNP discovery of these samples.

**Objective** Our ultimate goal with this genotypic data is to search for variants (both SNPs and indels) that fall within genes from a cohort of gene families, which may be responsible for phenotypic variation that we have assessed among our sample plants.

**Background** The RNA alignments use a reference genome of the species I am dealing with, and following [GATK best practices](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360035531192-RNAseq-short-variant-discovery-SNPs-Indels-) and produced a VCF file for each of my samples.

There are three things that give me pause,

1. Am I correct in merging the .VCF files after calling SNPs, rather than merging .BAM files and then calling SNPs?
2. What filters are required for MAF, read-depth, base call quality, missing data, snp proximity to each other and proximity to indels, etc.

- Should I produce plots to make these decisions?

3. Lastly how do I deal with specific allele expression skewing the results, my assumption so far is that other studies seem to have accounted for this by merely using a low bar for the MAF filter (such as >= 0.1), thus ensuring that as many true SNPs as possible are captured.

Any insight into any of these questions, or a point in the direction of where I might find it, would be much appreciated.